# Force determined return type for member from method, when return type member has union types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In the following method:

```
private async getJobExecutionIds(): Promise<Athena.ListQueryExecutionsOutput> {
    const params = { NextToken: this.nextToken, MaxResults: 50 };
    const response = await this.athena.listQueryExecutions(params).promise();
    if (response.QueryExecutionIds instanceof Array) {
      return response;
    }
    throw new Error("No Athena QueryExecutionIds");
}
```

I have added the check for `response.QueryExecutionIds instanceof Array` in order to guarantee for my user to be safely rely on the existence of `QueryExecutionIds: string[] | undefined`

However when I used this method:

```
const executionIds = await this.getJobExecutionIds();
```

I still can not rely on `executionIds.QueryExecutionIds` being there as `string[]`.

How can I achieve this in a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that while typescript has [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), it's can't reason about a property inside a type, only about types. You need to "help" typescript a bit, to understand that if `response.QueryExecutionIds instanceof Array`, it's actually a completely new type.

So the first step is to define this new type, based on the original type. In this type, `QueryExecutionIds` can't be undefined. Here are two options, choose what you like best:

```
type ListQueryExecutionsOutputSafe = Athena.ListQueryExecutionsOutput & {QueryExecutionIds: string[]}
interface ListQueryExecutionsOutputSafe extends Athena.ListQueryExecutionsOutput {
  QueryExecutionIds: string[];
}
```

The next step is to define some custom type guard:

```
const checkIfListQueryExecutionsOutputIsSafe = (obj: Athena.ListQueryExecutionsOutput): obj is ListQueryExecutionsOutputSafe => 
  !!obj.QueryExecutionIds;
```

and finally:

```
  private async getJobExecutionIds(): Promise<ListQueryExecutionsOutputSafe> {
    const params = {NextToken: this.nextToken, MaxResults: 50};
    const response = await this.athena.listQueryExecutions(params).promise();
    if (checkIfListQueryExecutionsOutputIsSafe(response)) {
      return response;
    }
    throw new Error("No Athena QueryExecutionIds");
  }
```

---

But why stop here? let's make everything generic:

```
type TypeWithNotNullProp<T, SafeKey extends keyof T> = T & {[K in SafeKey]-?: T[K]}

const checkSafeProp = <T, SafeKey extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: SafeKey): obj is TypeWithNotNullProp<T, SafeKey> => 
  !!obj[key];



  private async getJobExecutionIds(): Promise<ListQueryExecutionsOutputSafe> {
    const params = {NextToken: this.nextToken, MaxResults: 50};
    const response = await this.athena.listQueryExecutions(params).promise();
    if (checkSafeProp(response, 'QueryExecutionIds')) {
      return response;
    }
    throw new Error("No Athena QueryExecutionIds");
  }
```

I usually put `TypeWithNotNullProp` and `checkSafeProp` at some utils file, it's very handy to deal with different apis.